# Solving Ax=b, where A is an unknown Toeplitz matrix, x and b are known.

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve an equation of the form $Ax=b$, where $A$ is an unknown *Toeplitz* matrix, while $x$ and $b$ are known.

If one knows corresponding Matlab procedure, it'll be great.

Answer (score 2):

You have more unknowns ($2n-1$) than equations ($n$)

Comment: Perhaps MrZ is assuming $A$ is symmetric?